# Which macOS versions are officially supported by Apple?

Tags: macos

Where can one figure out which macOS versions are supported by Apple, and in which support stage they are?

I ask because I always assumed that both the latest and the one previous version were supported. As of this writing, the latest version is 10.12 - Sierra. I just happened to land in [the Wikipedia page for 10.11 - El Capitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) and see the below info. Where do Wikipedia authors get this? Is there a corresponding Apple website to check?

[image]

Comment: I think it's simply guessing based on experience with older systems. With the release of macOS 10.current.0 no security updates for 10.current-3.X were released any more: with the release of 10.14.0 *Uber Sierra* which is expected in autumn 2018 (if they adhere to the usual cycles) El Capitan will be abandonned.

Comment: Related: [What is Apple's policy for supporting security updates on older versions of OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47664/what-is-apples-policy-for-supporting-security-updates-on-older-versions-of-os-x)